# Can I change the default `login_required value for all pages in Django-CMS?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-cms

I've been tasked with creating a Django-CMS web application that should only be available to logged-in users. After some struggling I've settled to just check "Login Required" on Permissions for all pages, but it is bothersome to do this by hand (and potentially dangerous to forget to set it to true.

So I was wondering: is there a way to change the default value of the `login_required` `BooleanField` on django-cms' `pagemodel.py`? Or maybe I can somehow override the API's `create_page` method to put the default value there?

I don't know if there may be a situation in the future where we will want there to be some publicly-available pages, but if there's another way to do this rather than to set this flag to true on each Page, please let me know. I'm using Python 2.7.x, Django 1.11.x and Django-CMS 3.4.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it as follows:

In the project's `middleware.py` I placed the following:

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

```
def login_exempt(view):
    view.login_exempt = True
    return view


class LoginRequiredMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        return self.get_response(request)

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        if getattr(view_func, 'login_exempt', False):
            return

        if 'admin/login' in request.path:
            return

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return

        return login_required(view_func)(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
```

Which I had to add to my `settings.py`'s `MIDDLEWARE` list as `'my_project.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware'`.

And then in my `urls.py` I had to only decorate those URLs which should *not* require authentication:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^login/$', login_exempt(my_project_views.login_user), name='login'),
    url(r'^login$', login_exempt(my_project_views.login_user), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$', login_exempt(my_project_views.logout_user), name='logout'),
    ...
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create some middleware so you can process all requests & ensure users are logged in.

Docs are here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware

You'd do something like;

```
def process_request(self, request):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('login')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been battling to get the same thing going in Django 2. There are a number of posts our here with bits and pieces of relevant information but I couldn't get it working with any one of those answers. Here is how I got this working in Django 2.1:

1. Create a new directory called `middleware` in your `project` directory (the same directory where you find settings.py
2. Create a new file called `login_middleware.py` inside that directory. In order for Django to activate this file, you need to also add `__init__.py` into this directory.
3. In the `login_middleware.py` place the code you see below.
4. Now you should add this to your `settings.py` file by adding this line to the MIDDLEWARE list:   `'your_project_name.middleware.login_middleware.AlwaysForceLogin',`

   - login_middleware = the name of your file (login_middleware.py)
   - AlwaysForceLogin = the name of the class (see below)

Content of `login_middleware.py`:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class AlwaysForceLogin(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        print("Processing now...")
        if not request.user.is_authenticated and not 'login' in request.GET:
            return redirect('/login?login=true')
```

Important note: I ran into an infinite loop because even the login page was being redirected. This rather ugly 'not login in request.GET' hack seems sub-optimal, but I have no better solutions at the moment. Open to feedback.

```
├── mysite
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── mysite
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   │   ├── middleware
|   │   │   ├── login_middleware.py
```